# Packages at http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu natty main are empty

Tags: ubuntu-natty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ros-diamondback-desktop-full on Ubuntu 11.04, but I noticed that the packages at http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-amd64/ are empty. Are the packages for Natty not ready yet?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9893/packages-at--http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu-natty-main-are-empty/) by [ushadow](https://answers.ros.org/users/498/ushadow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-05-04

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, they are still setting up for Natty packages. You can check the status of builds here: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/diamondback.html

See also: http://answers.ros.org/question/618/ros-packages-for-ubuntu-1104

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-05-24**:
Good to know.  Thanks!

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-05-24**:
It's on the order of week(s)

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-05-24**:
Interesting.  Any idea on a timeframe?  Are we talking a week?  A month?  6?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-05-24**:
we're still rolling out patches and fixes in the low-level stacks.  Natty introduced *a lot* of changes, including Python, GCC, Boost, and more, so it's taking longer than anticipated.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-24**:
Taking a look at the build status page linked above, there are still some outstanding debs that aren't building and are notable. Specifically I see vision_opencv and simulator_stage in the red (ie broken). Many packages are built though, so progress is being made.

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-05-24**:
Any updates for this?  I'd love to install the desktop installation on Natty, so that I can have working graphics.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-05-04**:
fergs' answer is correct.  We only just spun up the repository today, and numerous stacks are not yet compatible with natty.  We appreciate any patches from the community.